# local var destroy when throw e for refer in c++?

Tags: c++, reference

Code sample one:

```
try {
    exception e;
    throw e;
} catch(exception& refer)
```

Code sample two:

```
exception& method()
{
    exception e;
    return e;
}
```

Some books mentioned that code sample one is ok, code two is wrong due to `e` in it is a local variable and will destroy when the function ends, but my question is why is sample code one okay? Isn't the `e` a local variable too?

Comment: Why would you return an exception rather than throw?

Comment: I just write code sample not write actual code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in sample one, `e` is local to the try block, and is destroyed upon exiting that scope.  But when you throw, the compiler makes a copy (or move), who's lifetime is extended to the end of the catch block, and it is this copy to which the reference `refer` refers.

For figuring out what the compiler does in cases like this, I always like to pull out my `Noisy` class.

```
#include <iostream>

class Noisy
{
public:
    Noisy()
        { std::cout << "Noisy default construct\n"; }
    Noisy(Noisy const&)
        { std::cout << "Noisy copy\n"; }
    Noisy(Noisy&&)
        { std::cout << "Noisy move\n"; }
    ~Noisy()
        { std::cout << "Noisy destroy\n"; }
    Noisy& operator=(Noisy const&)
        { std::cout << "Noisy copy assign\n"; return *this; }
    Noisy& operator=(Noisy&&)
        { std::cout << "Noisy move assign\n"; return *this; }
    void swap(Noisy&)
        { std::cout << "Noisy swap\n"; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "in try block\n";
        Noisy n;
        std::cout << "about to throw n\n";
        throw n;
        std::cout << "end of try block\n";
    }
    catch (Noisy & n)
    {
        std::cout << "in catch block\n";
    }
    std::cout << "after catch\n";
}
```

Comment: its interesting that in the second case he returns e not &e but this is invalid only because he put & as the return type. THe compiler cannot make a copy of e and return its address because it have nowhere to put it (I assume)